# Tomcat 8 java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, securitymanager

I am deploying a web service (which uses `METRO 2.0` library and includes it in the `war` file) on `tomcat` with `security manager` enabled

```
-Djava.security.manager
-Djava.security.policy=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.6\conf\catalina.policy
```

and I am getting the following exception

```
    SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] 
 com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized 
    WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 
    constraint violation: loader (instance of 
    org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a 
    different type with name "javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNsForm"
     java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of 
    org/apache/catalina/loader/ParallelWebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a 
    different type with name "javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNsForm"
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal
    (WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2268)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
    $PrivilegedFindClassByName.run(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
    $PrivilegedFindClassByName.run(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:144)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass
    (WebappClassLoaderBase.java:809)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass
    (WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass
    (WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl$1.<clinit>
    (PropertyInfoImpl.java:365)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName
    (PropertyInfoImpl.java:365)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName
    (PropertyInfoImpl.java:340)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes
    (ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:136)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes
    (RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:86)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.size
    (ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:78)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.hasNext(AbstractList.java:351)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (ModelBuilder.java:255)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (ModelBuilder.java:209)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo
    (ModelBuilder.java:315)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.calcRef(TypeRefImpl.java:92)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.TypeRefImpl.getTarget(TypeRefImpl.java:69)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget
    (RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:58)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeRefImpl.getTarget
    (RuntimeTypeRefImpl.java:51)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get
    (ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:74)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.get
    (ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:77)
        at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (ModelBuilder.java:255)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:100)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (ModelBuilder.java:209)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:95)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo
    (RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo
    (ModelBuilder.java:315)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo
    (ModelBuilder.java:330)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet
    (JAXBContextImpl.java:466)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build
    (JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:106)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext
    (JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run
    (AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run
    (AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext
    (AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess
    (AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel
    (RuntimeModeler.java:258)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel
    (EndpointFactory.java:338)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint
    (EndpointFactory.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters
    (DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse
    (DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
        at 
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized
    (WSServletContextListener.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart
    (StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal
    (StandardContext.java:5189)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal
    (ContainerBase.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.access$000(ContainerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run
    (ContainerBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$PrivilegedAddChild.run
    (ContainerBase.java:140)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run
    (HostConfig.java:1805)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
    (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

On the other hand, without `security manager` - everything deploys fine.

After some searching, I came to understanding that the problem is that `javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlNsForm` is found in both `tomcat` libraries and in the `METRO 2.0`.

So I have 2 questions:

1.Is there some kind of property in `catalina.policy` that could be set to avoid   this problem.

2.Is there any other way to resolve this conflict without removing `Metro 2.0` from `war`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was not to use the entire bundle of `Metro 2.0` - only some of the libraries of the bundle (added as `jars` not as entire bundle inside `netbeans`)